# How do I scale from one side side only?

Tags: transforms, edit-mode

How do I scale from one side side only?

I want to keep the left side of a object in place, but scale it smaller from the right.

See this screen shot:

[image]

I want it to end up like this:

[image]

But I had to scale and move to get that.

Comment: Why do you need to scale? Just grab the vertices on the "right side" in edit mode and move them to the left.

Comment: @OcasoProtal yea but that won't keep the origin relative.

Comment: @Petah Why not recenter the origin afterwards?

Comment: @gandalf3 yes in this case recentering the origin after moving the vertices would work. But in other situations this would not be the case.

Comment: @Petah Unless you have your origin placed in a really strange spot (i.e. not relative to any geometry) then I can't think of any cases where this isn't the case. You can always position it using the 3D cursor.

Comment: @gandalf3 such as the origin being on the edge of an object?

Comment: @gandalf3 also it is hard to reposition the object after scaling it so 1 edge is in the place it used to be.

Comment: @Petah You could snap the 3D cursor to one edge, scale, then snap the origin to the 3D cursor. Anyway, it doesn't really make a difference as it is possible to scale based on the 3D cursor (as in stacker's answer).

Comment: @gandalf3 I can see that your points make a valid alternative. But I think stacker's answer fits my problem the best.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Set the [*Pivot Point*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html) to *3D Cursor* and the 3D Cursor to the end that should not move while scaling.

[image]

For an exact position you may want to snap the *3D Cursor* to the selection (Mesh -> Snap -> Cursor to Selection).

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to try *vertex slide* in edit mode. Select the vertices you want to move and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

*Note: this is specific to mesh edit-mode and assumed you have topology which can slide.*

Comment: I tried this, but it also seems to shrink them too. Also in edit mode it is easy enough to move the vertices as per the comments on the question.

Comment: <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to only slide into the y-direction

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the "Edit Mode"
2. If what I can see is a rectangle, then select both the vertices (First select one vertex, then also select the other vertex, by holding down the shift key.) If it is a cuboid, then you need to select four vertices. [image]
3. Use the red arrow to move on only one side.